# jQuery Library conflicts with Prototype Framework

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, conflict

I am including two JavaScript files in my html page. The first is: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1/prototype.js

It is needed to create some hovercards (http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/prototip2/).

The second JavaScript is the latest jQuery. I need this to create some animation on the page.

When both JavaScript files are in the page my hovercards stop working. When I remove the jQuery file the hovercards are back.

Why is the jQuery stopping the `prototype.js` file from working? How can I resolve this so I can use both?

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Comment: Why do you want to use both libraries in the first place? You can almost certainly find tools for use with one or the other library to do things like "hovercards" and animations.  To put it another way, when searching for tools and pre-made plugins etc. it's a really good idea to stick with one framework when possible.

Comment: I am using pre-made solution, so I went with what the developer used. Once I tackled the second feature it was using a diff library. I had already dont a lot of work with the first. But, good point. I'll be sure to take your advice next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) like this:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) { 
  $(function() {
    // more code using $ as alias to jQuery
  });
})(jQuery);
//code with the other library using $
```

Comment: Hi Nicola, 


I added your code but now my jquery animations are not working, but the hovercards are. 

I do not know what you mean: // more code using $ as alias to jQuery.

 Do I add a link to the jquery library where the comment is? What does the this mean: //code with the other library using $

Comment: I don't know what to use that code. Where does the link to the jquery and javascript go?

Comment: // more code using $ as alias to jQuery means that after that comment you can use $ as an alias for jQuery: you should put all the code relative to jQuery inside that function. After that function you can put your prototype code using $ . if you post your code it's easier to help